# check if certain position is showing in ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

I want to know if a certain position in a list view is currently shown. Let us say I have a list of 20 Items, how do i check if postion 9 i among the shown items as there may be multiple items on the screen.

In my App, i automatically scroll a List view for the user so i need to know if this postion is already somewhere on the screen

Comment: Answer the question or provide a reason for the down vote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below code snippet for checking a specific list position is currently visible in list view.

```
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
   //Specify the list index that you want to check visibility
    int listItemIndex = 9;
    View listItem = getListView().getChildAt(listItemIndex);
    if (listItem  != null && listItem .getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
     //The list item is visible
    }
}
```

Get all list items visible on the scroll

```
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        //Loop to get tids of all completely visible List View's item scrolled on screen
        for (int listItemIndex = 0; listItemIndex<=getListView().getLastVisiblePosition()- getListView().getFirstVisiblePosition(); listItemIndex++) {
        //Specify the list index that you want to check visibility
        View listItem = getListView().getChildAt(listItemIndex);
        if (listItem  != null && listItem .getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            //The list item is visible
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanx for the idea had to tweak it up to listitem.isShown()